# The contrapositive of the statement "For all positive real number $x$, there exists an integer n such that $\frac{1}{n} < x.$"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-languages

I am trying to express contrapositive of the statement "For all positive real number $x$, there exists an integer n such that $\frac{1}{n} < x.$" in formal language.

The universe for both $x$ an $n$ is the set of all real numbers.

I am confused whether the expression for the contrapositive of the statement in formal language should be

\begin{align}
\forall x,(\forall n,(n\in \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \frac{1}{n} \ge x) \rightarrow (x \notin \mathbb{R}^+)).
\end{align}

or

\begin{align}
\forall x,(\forall n,(n\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge \frac{1}{n} \ge x) \rightarrow (x \notin \mathbb{R}^+)).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement, expressed as an implication with free variable $x$, is
$$
x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow \exists{n}:\left(n\in\mathbb{Z}\;\wedge\;\frac{1}{n}<x \right).
$$
Its contrapositive, then, is
$$
\neg\exists{n}:\left(n\in\mathbb{Z}\;\wedge\;\frac{1}{n}<x \right)\rightarrow x\not\in\mathbb{R}^{+},
$$
or
$$
\forall{n}:\left(n\in\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\frac{1}{n}\ge x \right)\rightarrow x\not\in\mathbb{R}^{+}.
$$

Comment: In words: "if for all integers $n$ you have $\frac1n \ge x$ then $x$ is not a positive real number".  In reality you need to ignore $n=0$ since it does not have a reciprocal, and you can conclude $x <-1$